# ORA-02289 Sequence does not exist while trying to insert in Oracle 19c database with Doctrine 2

Tags: doctrine-orm, sequence, symfony5, oracle19c

I have:

- php 7.4
- Symfony Version 5 (running in a VM) with
- Ubuntu 20.4
- doctrine/orm 2.8.2
- doctrine/dbal 2.12.1

Now I try to insert one dataset into a oracle database table with this annotation:

```
@ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="SEQUENCE")
@ORM\SequenceGenerator(sequenceName="SCHEMA.SEQ_USERS", initialValue=1, allocationSize=100)
```

and the sequence SEQ_USERS exists! And I'm at a loos! Because I always get the error message:

ORA-02289 Sequence does not exist

Did someone has this problem and found out a solution?

Thank you for any hint.

Comment: Are you sure you're allowed to specify a schema as part of the name parameter? That looks like a sequence called "SCHEMA.SEQ_USERS", not a sequence called "SEQ_USERS" in schema "SCHEMA". And are you sure you need to specify the schema?

Comment: You are Right. It's not necessary to have the schema-name before the sequence name. I have tested it also without the owner but this does work neither!

Comment: I'm facing the same Problem. Have you discovered a solution? Inserting using SQL Developer works, but over php/doctrine i get this error.

Comment: Yes I've got something but I don't know the way anymore, sorry...

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that Doctrine 2 was ignoring my sequences defined. It kept trying to call {Table-Name}_SEQ for some reason. So, I just created some Oracle Synonyms to handle the differences.